# SQL Server FileTable - IP Address instead of Host name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filestream, filetable

Is there any way to configure SQL Server so that the function `FileTableRootPath()` returns an IP address instead of the host name?

Some of our servers are not in the domain and are accessible only by their IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few options, this should give you the IP of the SQL box:

```
SELECT 
      client_net_address = CASE WHEN client_net_address = '<local machine>' 
                                THEN '127.0.0.1' 
                                ELSE client_net_address 
                           END  
    , local_net_address = ISNULL(local_net_address, '127.0.0.1')
    , server_name = @@SERVERNAME
    , machine_name = SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE session_id = @@SPID;
```

or if you have `xp_cmdshell` enabled, you could do something like:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'ipconfig'
```

Comment: thanks, of course, we know many ways to determine the addresses of the server interfaces. we want to know, maybe there is a setting that will allow built-in functions, such as FileTableRootPath (), to return a specific ip address from all assigned interfaces.

Comment: I'm not aware of `Defined Functions` that specifically do that.  You could make a `User Defined Function` and use the above code though.